# Sudo password not working for fedora28

Tags: fedora, sudo, upgrade

I upgraded from Fedora 26 to Fedora 28 by using `sudo dnf "system-upgrade download --releasever=28"` command.

Now I can login to Gnome, but `sudo` is not working. When I do `sudo -i`, it asks for the password for my username. I login to Gnome with the same username but that password doesn't work in the terminal. Now I cannot check the wheel group or do `visudo`, as I don't have access.

Comment: Fill a [bugreport](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_file_a_bug_report)

Comment: Log in as root and examine the `sudoers` file to see why it does not work for you.

Comment: @Kusalananda How to login as root? I didn't set any root user in fedora28.

Comment: @yogeshkakde If you didn't set a root user while installing (which is odd) or you just don't remember the password, boot into single-user mode and reset it. When `grub` shows the kernel that you normally boot into, select it and press `e`. On the next screen, go down to the kernel line that starts with `linux`, change the `ro` to `rw init=/sysroot/bin/sh`. `Ctrl X` to boot into single user mode. When the prompt comes up, enter `chroot /sysroot/` and that will get you into `/`. Enter `passwd` and then enter and confirm the new root password. You can now login and become root with `su -`.